# What does the U mean in UTM=(32, 'U')?

Tags: utm, geolocation, naming-conventions

I've come across code which specifies `UTM=(32, 'U')`. Is there a common convention around UTM I can understand this through, or is there not enough information here to determine the geographic location?

Comment: This might have the answer: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30193/how-to-convert-from-epsg4326-to-wgs84-utm-32u

Answer (score 12, accepted):

UTM 32U is one tile of the [UTM 32N zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system). This image from [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTM-Koordinatensystem#cite_note-TOP50-7) ([here](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Datei:Utmzonenugitterp.png) the link to the following image) should explain it clearly:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The 'U' in this UTM notation refers to a specific lattitude band I believe- see 'Latittude bands' here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system